# Proof of no unbiased estimation of standard deviation.

Tags: st.statistics

It is well known that for iid random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ with variance $\sigma^2$ that

$$\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline X)^2$$

gives an unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$, but

$$\sqrt{ \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline X)^2 }$$

is not an unbiased estimator for $\sigma$.

Is there a way to formulate precisely and prove that there does not exist an unbiased estimator $f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ for $\sigma$ that works for all probability distributions?

Answer (score 6):

Consider the case $n=2$.  By scaling and translation we must have $f(x,y) = c |x-y|$ for some constant $c$.  But for e.g. a Bernoulli distribution $E[c|X_1 - X_2|] = c p(1-p)$, and this can't be $\sigma = \sqrt{p(1-p)}$ for all $p$.

Comment: Similarly for $n=3$: we must have $f(0,0,0) = f(1,1,1) = 0$ and $f(x,y,z) = c$ for all other $(x,y,z) \in \{0,1\}^3$.  Then for a Bernoulli distibution $E[f(X_1,X_2,X_3)] = 3 c p (1-p)$ which can't be $\sqrt{p(1-p)}$.

Comment: Similarly for any $n$: let $f(X_1,\ldots,X_n) = c_k$ if $k$ of the $X_i$ are $0$ and the other $n-k$ are $1$.  We must have $c_0 = 0$.  Now for a Bernoulli distribution with small $p$, $E[f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)] = n p c_1 + O(p^2)$, and this can't be $\sqrt{p(1-p)}$.

Comment: Can you explain in detail why $f(x,y) = c|x-y|$ is true? What exactly do you mean by "scaling and translation we must have $f(x,y) = c|x-y|$"

Comment: Actually that's not quite true: what would be true is that $f(x,y) + f(y,x) = c |x-y|$.  But of course we can assume $f$ is symmetric in $x$ and $y$.  The point is that $E[f(aX_1+b,aX_2+b)] = |a|E[f(X_1,X_2)]$ because $\sigma_{aX+b}=|a| \sigma_X$.

Comment: How do you conclude $E[f(aX1+b,aX2+b)]=|a|E[f(X1,X2)]$? What justifies pulling $a$ outside of $f$ and outside of the expectation?

Comment: If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent samples from a distribution with standard deviation $\sigma$, then $a X_1+b$ and $a X_2 + b$ are independent samples from a distribution with standard deviation $|a| \sigma$.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how the independence allows the variable $a$ to escape the function $f$.

Comment: By assumption, $E[f(X_1,X_2)]$ is supposed to be the standard deviation of the random variable $X_1$ and $X_2$ are sampled from.

Comment: Could you write out a complete detailed proof?

Comment: I don't think the proof is quite right (like others here seem to think, too).  The scaling and translation property is only guaranteed to hold for expectations, *e.g.* we must have $E\bigl(f(X_1+c,X_2+c)\bigr) = E\bigl(f(X_1, X_2)\bigr)$, but I don't think anything guarantees $f(X_1+c,X_2+c) = f(X_1, X_2)$  here.

Answer (score 4):

If the statistical model consists in assuming $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ to be iid Bernoulli with unknown success probablity $p\in[0,1]$, then a function $\kappa:[0,1]\rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ admits an unbiased estimator iff $\kappa$ is polynomial of degree at most $n$. ("Only if" is clear by writing down the expectation of any estimator, "if" follows by observing that $\prod_{i=1}^kX_i$
has expectation $p^k$ and using linearity.) Now $\sigma(p)=\sqrt{p(1-p)}$ is not polynomial, hence does not admit any unbiased estimator here.

The above is known from sufficiently good textbooks of mathematical statistics, see for example Pfanzagl (1994), Parametric Statistical Theory, page 72, where the equivalent (by a sufficiency reduction) case of one binomial observation is treated. Pfanzagl credits a paper of Kolmogorov (1950), Unbiased estimates, who however cites Halmos (1946), The theory of unbiased estimation, which contains at least the basic idea.